# Embed Code in Drupal

Tags: asp.net, drupal, embed, query-string

I am not familiar with Drupal but our clients report that what we provide as embed isn't working with drupal.

Our embed code will be

`<iframe id="ivideoframe" src="https://mywebsite/Player.aspx?q=IsahXh4JBPTq9sc%252b2j4zmaJvfFIagPpqAIBQIZpQTGUxPzzL8g44uVrsRGGRbDnSk5IO3kBeGI%252b211on7BfXBL6UjrXe%252fI%252bhftSaavtHay8%253d" height="419" width="665" toolbar="no" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

What I understand from client is the query string letter "?q" has some issue with drupal. Can some one help me to understand how this code will result in error when used in drupal?

Comment: are you trying to embed this code in content body ?

Comment: Yes! It seems to be...

Comment: ok than check text format is set to full HTML

Comment: `q` is used to identify the internal router path _on the server side_. So putting `q=` in an external URL will have no affect on the consuming Drupal website. The problem is very likely to be what @Soni is hinting at - a problem with the text format. Whether that's a permissions problem, or just a problem with the wrong format being used is impossible to say without more info

Comment: you can output url by using drupal function url(). For that you need to enable module php filter and make text format as "php code". It will resolve issue with ?q

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting this embedded code into a block, or a CCK field of some sort (body, text, etc), you'll want to make sure that the "Text Format" is set to either Full HTML or one that allow the use of full html.

Even Full HTML can sometimes be buggy with iFrame's, I've found.  We've found the best practice is to actually create your own Text Format called "Raw HTML" that allows everything and doesn't try to format things at all.  You can create it at [Admin --> Configuration --> Content authoring --> Text Formats].

Then once you've created the format, simply choose that custom format on the field that contains the iFrame embed code.